# Sqlite blob size

Tags: sqlite

My SQlite DB seems to be bigger than I estimated. 
How can I check the distribution or whats causing this.
It has some BLOB fields. Even after deleting the BLOB data, size doesn't seem to change

Thank u
Sun

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you try to run the [`vacuum`](http://sqlite.org/lang_vacuum.html) SQlite command? This should rebuild the DB, bring down the size.